# Separate language and currency to different local IDs

Tags: angular, currency-formatting

my goal is to use different locale ids for language and currency: the currency pipe format is depended on the local id, which tells it what kind of number, date and currency symbol to use. But, also my language service is depended on the local id (multi language project, using angular i18n internalization with different build for each language requires the use of the local id to determine the current language).

How can I set for example, English language with any other currency and number/date formatting? 
Or for the more general case, any language with any currency?